# How to prevent tracking automatic page reload?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using GTM/GA to track a site that reloads (http refresh) itself every 30 seconds. This makes pageviews meaningless. How does one track the original page load, but not reloads of the same page?

Answer (score -1):

For GA there is no difference between automatic and manual page refresh. It works by counting each refresh. There is no way to distinguish them from each other.

Although if you use javascript to refresh your website, you can try to [disable tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out) on page refresh and enable it on page load.

Comment: I like the idea of disabling tracking on further refreshes of same page. I don't see a way to disable/enable.

Comment: I was trying to set an exclusion rule on PageView tag that looked to see if HTTP REFERRER was same page or not. Any idea how to do that?